# What's the easiest way to prevent closing a dialog if the input validation false

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to prevent the user from entering invalid data in fields on edit forms and in the table edit cells. Because of the bound nature of inputs how can this be prevented?

Currently I get the red warning text for validation but this does not prevent saving the data.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid edits according to the validation logic should not be saved, although the UI elements are not reverted to show the old data. This assumes that the validation logic is implemented using App Maker constraints or using the onValidate event.